# Accessing items from different layout screens in android

Tags: android, layout, accessibility

I've added two layout screen in my application. 1. main.xml 2. second.xml. two classes Main.java and Second.java. Main.java has the`setContentView(R.layout.main);` and Second.java has `setContentView(R.layout.second);`. main.xml contains one button and one EditText view. while second.xml contains TextView. The problem that I'm facing is that when I try to access TextView in Second.java it does't show up in options, the only options shown are the items that are in main.xml file. Any idea how to resolve this issue?
I have modified `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also Second.java extends activity and it is under the same package as Main.java. Need Help Here.

Comment: You mean that your textview is not showing which is in second.xml? Put your code .

Comment: No, TextView is in second.xml, but I can't access it in the Second.java Class. When I write TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1); it shows error, instead it show in option button1,editText1.

Comment: put your second.java and second.xml

Comment: I think when you click button on main the text on Edittext will go to second layout or second.java??is this your question??

Comment: Now I see that my problem is that second.xml code is not being generated in R.java file, no idea what's the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused as I am a new user. I created two layouts which had two buttons on each layout. so whenever I tried to access that In Eclipse it showed me all the objects on both screens. the thing is that if you want to access any object on the layout access that using `findViewById()`, android will automatically access the local objects in that layout class which you are accessing. Don't get confused like me that which Button or TextView to access as both layouts have these items.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout that there is no error in any Layout or Manifest file. Because if your project contains any error in layout or any resource files , it won't generate the R.java file. Just try to Project>Clean.. the project and Project>Build Automatically.

I hope it will help you out...

Comment: I have added new layout in the project but its code is not being generated in the R.java file. What I am missing here?

Comment: I would suggest you to please post the code,if you can.So that i can actually get the idea of what is going wrong.